# Android:Where can I get the latest version SDK's open source project site?

Tags: android

I want to know the "open source project" web site of the latest SDK version like SDK13,is there anyone help me??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have no release source code for that yet, if they did it would be on

http://source.android.com/

External Reference, although you can Google a lot more ...

http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/Google-IO-show-and-Android-31/

*"There was apparently no word on when Android 3.0 or 3.1 would be released as open source code, an event that Google said would be delayed indefinitely back in March."*

Answer (score 0):

I think that they haven't released the source code of SDK13, yet.

Comment: I think that Google hasn't announced the honeycomb's source code yet, because of the Ice Cream Sandwich. They said it on the Google I/O Conference, so probably sometimes soon...